# Battery efficiency

Tags: electricity, batteries, aircraft, electrochemistry

I have 4000 mah 4 cell and a
5000 mah 3 cell
Which battery is more efficient.
Higher mah or more number of cell.
I am selecting batteries for rc plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean 'Which has the most energy, could theoretically run my RC plane the longest'

You need to take voltage into account

We'll assume these are 3V LiPo batteries for the calculations, but actually the volt per cell doesn't matter for your question.

Power = volts * amps = watts so

(3V * 4 cells) * 4 A-Hr = 48 W-Hr

(3V * 3 cells) * 5 A-Hr = 45 W-Hr

It's almost a tie.

You'd need to look at the motor next (what voltage is it most efficient at)